# Is there a way to make a Hotspot on Win10 with internet sharing and connections between PC and clients?

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, router, internet

My router is pretty slow, but I have a good network card. I want to stream my PC's display to my phone, and to do that, I would like to make a hotspot on Win10 that allows connections to the internet and connections from my phone to my PC. Problem is, if I set up Internet Sharing in the Win10 options, I can reach the internet but not my PC, requests to the gateway on my phone just time out. Is there any way to do what I want?

Just in case this helps, I have a Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9260 160MHz on Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 21H2

Comment: Are you trying to share the internet with the same adapter your using to connect the laptop to the internet?

Comment: Instead of using Internet Sharing, try to [Create a Hosted Network](https://networkbees.com/revised-steps-to-create-a-hosted-network-in-windows-10/) and share your internet connection with this hosted network, as explained in the link. This might work better.